# jquery formatCurrency symbol position

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I'm using the jQuery formatCurrency plugin (https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) to, well, format currency.

However, I don't see anything in the docs about the position of the symbol. Some regions use the currency symbol before the number ($15,000) and some use after (15.000$).

Does anyone know if this position option is supported in the plugin, or how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the [plugin itself](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) and accompanying international support files, it's pretty easy to set up a custom region for yourself that puts the currency symbol where you want it.

In the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage) you will see the `positiveFormat` and `negativeFormat` notation is how you specify the order of the currency symbol (`%s`) and number (`%n`).

So, if you wanted to create a file for French Canadian usage, where I believe the $ sign is conventionally on the right, you could create a file called `jquery.formatcurrency.cad-f.js` or whatever and set the positive and negative formats like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.formatCurrency.regions['cad-f'] = {
    symbol: '$',
    positiveFormat: '%n %s',
    negativeFormat: '-%n %s',
    decimalSymbol: '.',
    digitGroupSymbol: ',',
    groupDigits: true
};})(jQuery);
```

And because I always forget the simple stuff, don't forget to load your custom region and specify it as needed like this: `.formatCurrency({ region: 'cad-f' })`.

Comment: thanks! rather than creating a new locale I just specified the positiveFormat option as you'd shown.